# How can I implement vertical, center-locked list view in android?

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, custom-controls

I'm trying to accomplish the following (on my Android application):

1. I want to have vertical list of views (each will contain mostly text views).
2. I want that list to be centered locked, meaning that there will be a selected item all the time which will be in the center of my list.
3. I want the selected item will be marked (basically, I want a marker in the center of the list, which each item that will be under it will be selected.

In a few words, I want to achieve similar effect such as the gallery widget, but vertical and with items that are not images.

Update: here is an image:
[image: List Sketch]

Thanks!

Comment: Must it be an `AdapterView` implementation?

Comment: can u add a snapshot/sketch of what u want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to implement by listview, but I fount somebody write a control like what you said; as follow image;

each item is a view, you can set one list and the height, it may be what you want.
source code: http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

[image]

Comment: Hi @Mejonzhan, I know this project. I can't include it in mine. All I need is that center lock mechanism.